# Smart contract error: Ownable: caller is not the owner

Tags: c#, solidity, nethereum

When calling a method with the owner account, I get the above error...
"Smart contract error: Ownable: caller is not the owner"
Next, I will write my own codes:
Write Contract Method:

```
function setWalletLimit(address wallet, uint256 amount,uint day) onlyOwner() public{
         
      uint256 date =  block.timestamp;

      uint endDate = date +  (day * 1 days);

      _Limited[_limitedCount] = LimitedAddress(wallet,amount,endDate);
      _addressLimited[wallet].push(_limitedCount);

      emit SetLimit(_limitedCount,_Limited[_limitedCount]);

      _limitedCount++;

    }
```

calling code in c#:

```
var privatekey = "";

 var url = "https://bsc-dataseed1.binance.org:443";

 var web3 = new Web3(new Account(privatekey), url);
```

```
string abi = "[{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"string\",\"name\":\"_name\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"internalType\":\"string\",\"name\":\"_symbol\",\"type\":\"string\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"_decimals\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"_supply\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"_txFee\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"_burnFee\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"_charityFee\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"_FeeAddress\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"tokenOwner\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"service\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"payable\",\"type\":\"constructor\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":true,\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"owner\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":true,\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"spender\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":false,\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"value\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"Approval\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":true,\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"previousOwner\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":true,\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"newOwner\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"OwnershipTransferred\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":false,\"internalType\":\"uint32\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint32\"},{\"components\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"Wallet\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"Amount\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"EndDate\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"indexed\":false,\"internalType\":\"struct LimitedAddress\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"tuple\"}],\"name\":\"SetLimit\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"anonymous\":false,\"inputs\":[{\"indexed\":true,\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"from\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":true,\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"to\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"indexed\":false,\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"value\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"Transfer\",\"type\":\"event\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"FeeAddress\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"wallet\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"ReportWalletLimit\",\"outputs\":[{\"components\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"Wallet\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"Amount\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"EndDate\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"internalType\":\"struct LimitedAddress[]\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"tuple[]\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"_BURN_FEE\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"_CHARITY_FEE\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"_TAX_FEE\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"_limitedCount\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint32\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint32\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"_owner\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"owner\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"spender\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"allowance\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"spender\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"amount\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"approve\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"bool\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"bool\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"account\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"balanceOf\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"decimals\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint8\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint8\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"spender\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"subtractedValue\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"decreaseAllowance\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"bool\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"bool\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"tAmount\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"deliver\",\"outputs\":[],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"account\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"excludeAccount\",\"outputs\":[],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"account\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"includeAccount\",\"outputs\":[],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"spender\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"addedValue\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"increaseAllowance\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"bool\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"bool\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"account\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"isExcluded\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"bool\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"bool\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"name\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"string\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"string\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"owner\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"tAmount\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"internalType\":\"bool\",\"name\":\"deductTransferFee\",\"type\":\"bool\"}],\"name\":\"reflectionFromToken\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"renounceOwnership\",\"outputs\":[],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"account\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"setAsCharityAccount\",\"outputs\":[],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"wallet\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"amount\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"day\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"setWalletLimit\",\"outputs\":[],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"symbol\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"string\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"string\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"rAmount\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"tokenFromReflection\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"totalBurn\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"totalCharity\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"totalFees\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[],\"name\":\"totalSupply\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"view\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"recipient\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"amount\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"transfer\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"bool\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"bool\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"sender\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"recipient\",\"type\":\"address\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"amount\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"transferFrom\",\"outputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"bool\",\"name\":\"\",\"type\":\"bool\"}],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"address\",\"name\":\"newOwner\",\"type\":\"address\"}],\"name\":\"transferOwnership\",\"outputs\":[],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"},{\"inputs\":[{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"_txFee\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"_burnFee\",\"type\":\"uint256\"},{\"internalType\":\"uint256\",\"name\":\"_charityFee\",\"type\":\"uint256\"}],\"name\":\"updateFee\",\"outputs\":[],\"stateMutability\":\"nonpayable\",\"type\":\"function\"}]";`
```

```
string contractaddress = "";

var contract = web3.Eth.GetContract(abi, contractaddress);

var function = contract.GetFunction("setWalletLimit");

string address = "";

await function.CallAsync<dynamic>(address,1,10);
```

Of course, I used other examples, but unfortunately I was not successful.
Thank you for guiding me in the form of an example.

I want to be able to call the declared method via nethereum c#

Comment: Are you calling the contract as the owner?

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting that error then you are not the contract owner, or the contract has a bug and is not checking the owner correctly.